# Adding HttpHandler causes an error on the server

Tags: asp.net

I have created an Httphandler in my application and I have uploaded the project on the server which is hosted by someone else.
I get an error which says 500 internal server error.

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

What is the issue? It works fine on my development server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check server log, because some time it may be possible that some reference does not work if you move to another machine, i face same problem but when i update reference files its work fine..

Comment: I know that I need an aspnet_isapi.dll reference for my project. But its the server that I dont have control over. What can I do>

Comment: but in server no need to config it..which panel are you using in hosting access ?

Comment: Web Hosting panel and domain control panel.

I know its happening because of the httphandler introduced in the project. If i remove the handler I dont get the error

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx

Do I have to include the handlers tag under webserver? Am I missing this ?

Comment: i think it i will automatically generate if you use any reference but some time if it may not exist there you have to add manually .

Comment: in most of case i will occur in IIS7 or later

Comment: Wai a sec. I dont know what I am missing here. The handler is there in my web.config, so what is missing?

Comment: @BhargavMistri let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2024/discussion-between-sly-chandan-and-bhargav-mistri)